# Keras model layer input size mismatch error

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have a simple and stupid question about the input size in Keras
If I create a model, for example

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(14, )))
for i in range(1):
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(104, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.05))
```

When I try to predict by passing a data say 
data = [-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0] and run

```
model.predict(data)
```

It would give an error

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape (14,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

But isn't the input_shape already defined as (14, 1), which is exactly what I've pass in?  I can solve this by using np.reshape(data, (1, 14)), but I'm still wondering what have I misunderstood about the array shapes here.

Comment: Well, the error is definitely not helpful. If you check `data.shape` it will give you `(14,)` so your data is definitely fits the shape you've given. The thing is keras wants you to feed in batches (that error is especially not helpful in this). So by reshaping to `(1, 14)` you make it into a batch of one. You can see this in [Keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense), in the example below it describes the input shape as `(*, 16)` for given `input_shape = (16,)` argument. You will also see that in your case, output shape will be in batches too. As in `(batch_size, 104)` specifically.

Comment: The error says everything, the input shape should be (None, 14), so you need to reshape the array as (1, 14), not just (14,)

Comment: I see.  So Keras automatically wants you to include another dimension for batch_size, even if you are only testing it once.  Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your input list.
 Your data list contains 14 inputs. It is recommended to make the list in the list as follows.

```
data = [[-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0] ]
```